# Proof on the existence of n-th roots of non-negative real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, real-numbers

I can't figure out one part of the proof of this theorem 
from this document [Proof](http://www.northeastern.edu/ckottke/3150/nthroots.pdf).

It's the part where we suppose

$y^{n} < x$ Then we can choose a real number h such that
$0 < h < \frac{x-y^{n}}{n(y+1)^{n-1}} \wedge h<1$

I undestand that we want to choose such h that $(y+h)^{n}<x$. But I don't get it how we got that formula $\frac{x-y^{n}}{n(y+1)^{n-1}}$ and also why h has to be smaller than 1.

Could someone please describe it step by step how exactly we got that formula?

Comment: People call it intuition. There is no real way to tell how someone arrived at it. The inequality that $0<a<b\Rightarrow b^n-a^n<(b-a)nb^{n-1}$ serves as a motivation for the result.

Comment: Almost surely, the person who wrote the proof did the entire proof first, then at the end saw what inequalities $h$ needed to satisfy to make the proof valid, and then put that "magic" inequality at the beginning of the polished version of the proof. So the exact opposite of intuition.

Comment: @GregMartin Yeah, and this writing style is incredibly frustrating (even though it's universal). I wish authors wrote in the intuitive way and provided the justifications afterwards; I have no idea why this approach is considered to be inferior to current approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I think I understand it, here is the answer:
$(y+h)^{n} =y^{n}-(y^{n}-(y+h)^{n})<y^{n}+h\cdot n(y+h)^{n-1}$

Almost what we need but we need to somehow express $h$. Therefore we let $h<1$ so that $(y+h)^{n}<(y+1)^{n}$

also we want this number to be $<x$

$=> (y+h)^{n}<y^{n}+h\cdot n(y+h)^{n-1}<y^{n}+h\cdot n(y+1)^{n-1}<x$

$x>y^{n}+h\cdot n(y+1)^{n-1}$

Now we can express $h$ from this inequality and use it later in the proof.

We can see that if this number is less than x then also $(y+h)^{n}<x$ and that's what we need.